# How to plot the given trihexagonal network?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

Following my previous question

[How to plot the given graph (irregular tri-hexagonal) with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238649/how-to-plot-the-given-graph-irregular-tri-hexagonal-with-mathematica/238658?noredirect=1#comment602646_238658)

I need a 2D network of the Fig. $a$, something like Fig. $b$ with red points on all vertices. Since I have drawn Fig. $b$ manually, it is not precise and symmetric.
In this case, the blue and the violet edges have different lengths.

[image]

Comment: @cvgmt Here it is. Regards.

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Drawing a Kagome lattice for given geometry](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211927/125)

Comment: @kglr I had seen that question, but the answers given there were all for the regular case (for the case the graph has only one length)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can construct a hexagon with short edges (with length `1`) and long edges (with length `β >= 1`) using [`AnglePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[diamondcoords, diamond]

diamondcoords[β_: 1] := AnglePath @ 
   Thread[{{1, β, 1, β, 1, β}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} 2 Pi / 6}]

diamond[β_: 1] := {AbsoluteThickness[10], CapForm["Round"], 
  MapIndexed[{{Red, Blue}[[Mod[#2[[1]], 2, 1]]], Line @ #} &, 
     Partition[diamondcoords[β], 2, 1]], 
   Gray, AbsolutePointSize @ 7, Point @ diamondcoords[β]}
```

With default value (`β = 1`) we get a regular hexagon:

```
Row[{Graphics[diamond[], ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Graphics[diamond[2], ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Graphics[diamond[4], ImageSize -> Medium]}]
```

[image]

We translate `diamond[β]` to get a tiling of desired size:

```
ClearAll[translations]
translations[n_] := Prepend[{0, 0}][Join @@ 
   (Thread[{Range[-#, #, 2], -# }] & /@ Range[n])]

Graphics[Translate[diamond[],
  -# {1/2, 1} (Subtract @@@ CoordinateBounds[diamondcoords[]])] & /@ translations[5],
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[Translate[diamond[2], 
  -# {1/2,1} (Subtract @@@ CoordinateBounds[diamondcoords[2]])] & /@ translations[7], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[Translate[diamond[3],
  -# {1/2, 1} (Subtract@@@CoordinateBounds[diamondcoords[3]])] & /@translations[5], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[Translate[diamond[1/3],
  -# {1/2, 1} (Subtract@@@CoordinateBounds[diamondcoords[1/3]])] & /@ translations[5],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was what I meant.

Answer (score 7):

```
cp = CirclePoints[6];
hexagon = {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Polygon@cp, Red, PointSize@Large, Point@cp};
Graphics[hexagon]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[translations]
translations[n_] := Prepend[{0, 0}][Join @@ 
   (Thread[{Range[-#, #, 2], -# Sqrt[3]}] & /@ Range[n])];


Graphics[Translate[hexagon, #] & /@ translations[5]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[Translate[hexagon, #] & /@ translations[10]]
```

[image]